# Powershell cmd no output result

Tags: octopus-deploy, powershell-5.1

I'm installing a deployment tool and it runs the following PS cmd to check in if PS is available:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion"
```

However no output returns.

I'm expecting the following output return:
**System.Collections.Hashtable.PSVersion**

I've checked sys variables, reinstalled PS, So Im not sure why output is being blocked?

Any advice what else I need to check?